# Echoing in makefile before building dependencies

Tags: c, makefile

In my makefile I would like to print a process message (something like "Build $(PROJ_NAME) project...") before building the dependencies of a target. For example my target look like this one below:

```
$(PROJ_NAME): $(OBJS)
    echo "Build $(PROJ_NAME) project..."
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) --gc-sections "-T$(MISC_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).ld" ...
```

Executing this target my build message is printed after building the dependencies in $(OBJS). Is there any possibility to print a message before doing anything creating the target?

Comment: that is by design since, before you do the actions specified in PROJ_NAME, make takes care of the things you are specifically telling make to take care of before taking the actions you list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add another dependency before the object files, that is always made. Something like this:

```
$(PROJ_NAME): pre_build $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) --gc-sections "-T$(MISC_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).ld" ...

.PHONY: pre_build
pre_build:
    @echo "Build $(PROJ_NAME) project..."
```

This `pre_build` target will (in most normal cases) always be executed before the targets in `$(OBJS)`.

Comment: It is a bad practice to rely on the order of building prerequisites, since it is not specified and will not behave as expected on parallel builds.